# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException even after adding jar

Tags: java, exception, jar, classpath

I have exported my java as jar from eclipse and I get the below error when I execute the jar file.

```
java -jar xmlparser.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: 
com.sdm.massupload.xmlconfig.impl.ResourceConfig. Program will exit.
```

I have added xbean.jar to classpath and the jar is present in the physical location. below is the classpath file for the jar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" 
  path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Softwares/xmlbeans- 2.3.0/lib/jsr173_1.0_api.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Softwares/xmlbeans-   2.3.0/lib/xbean_xpath.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Softwares/xmlbeans-   2.3.0/lib/resolver.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Softwares/xmlbeans-    2.3.0/lib/xmlbeans-qname.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Softwares/xmlbeans-    2.3.0/lib/xbean.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="C:/Codebase/hdmport 
(1)/hdmport/hdmport/lib/common/xmlconfig.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see some extra spaces between the name (path). `xmlbeans-    2.3.0/lib/xbean.jar`

Comment: Apologies, that was due to copy paste into the stack overflow editor. The actual classpath file does not contain those extra spaces

Comment: what is this xml? who reads this xml file and how is it being used in your application ?

Comment: The xml contains DB table's structure that is read by a factory parser and is used in the later part of the application.

Answer (score 0):

This class `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException` is in the `xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar` library. You can download it from [this](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.3.0/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar) link and then add it as dependency to your project